# Group by in Pig latin and stream for each key

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig

I have my data in this format : `student_id, course_id,grade,other_information`. This is for large number of students, say billions. I have a perl script written to process data for a student. So thought of using hadoop framework to speed-up the process by streaming data of each student to the perl script.

This is how i am doing:

```
student_data = LOAD 'source' using PigStorage('\t') As (stud_id:string,...)
grp_student = group student_data by stud_id;
final_data = foreach grp_student {
    flat_data = flatten(grp_student)
    each_stud_data = generate flat_data;
    result = STREAM each_stud_data THROUGH 'some perl script';
}

store final_data into '/some_location';
```

Problem: I am getting this error `Syntax error, unexpected symbol at or near 'flatten'`. Tried to google but in vain. Can some one please help?

Answer (score 1):

A few hints: flatten is not allowed in nested foreach. generate must be the last statement.

About the `Stream` command [Pig docs](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.0/basic.html#stream):

```
About Data Guarantees
Data guarantees are determined based on the position of the streaming operator in the Pig script.

[...]
Grouped data – The data for the same grouped key is guaranteed to be provided to the streaming application contiguously
[...]
```

Hence, if you adapt your script to be able to cope with the fact that it gets all data for a group key contiguously, it might work out.

```
student_data = LOAD 'source' using PigStorage('\t') As (stud_id:string,...);
grp_student = GROUP student_data BY stud_id;
flat_data = FOREACH grp_student GENERATE FLATTEN(student_data);
result = STREAM flat_data THROUGH 'some perl script';
```